# Using same class for Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a menu using CSS Javascript. When clicked on the anchor tags, the submenu will become visible. I am attaching my code for this below. The problem is, that I created a common class for the anchor tags and used 'querySelectorAll' to target both the anchors. However, my code is working. Can anyone tell me what the problem is

```js
const USERINFO = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-trigger');
const subMenu = document.getElementById("login-subMenu");
const html = document.documentElement;

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

USERINFO.addEventListener("click", function() {
  subMenu.style.right = "0";
});

html.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target !== USERINFO) {
    subMenu.style.right = "-570px";

    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="USERINFO" class="menu-trigger">ABC</a>
  <div id="bgrdt" class="menu-trigger">
    <a href="">XYZ</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"However, my code is working"_ - so what's the problem then?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList<HTMLElement>`, which is a collection/container of zero, one _or more_ HTML elements - but your script treats `const USERINFO` as a singular element reference. You need to adjust your code to handle each case (zero, one, or more returned elements).

Comment: the code works if I just use 'querySelector' but only one anchor tag is being targeted (whatever is first)

Comment: Have a good read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 3):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns an iterable `NodeList` object that contains 0 or more nodes. This means you can't call `addEventListener` on it directly, so when you try to do that your code runs into this error:

```js
const USERINFO = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-trigger');
// ...
USERINFO.addEventListener("click", function() {
```

> `USERINFO.addEventListener` is not a function

That's because `USERINFO.addEventListener` is `undefined`.

To fix this, you could either use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get just the first element that matches your selector, or you could look through all the results of `querySelectorAll`. You could do this using its [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method, for example.